# Usage of のに in this sentence: じゃ、あたらしいのにかえましょう

Tags: meaning

Assuming the following sentence and its answer:

> にもつがおもくて、ふくろのひもがきれそうです。
> じゃ、あたらしいのにかえましょう。

I don't really understand why we have to use のに instead of を in the answer, actually I'd have answered like this:

じゃ、あたらしいをかえましょう。which would mean "Then let's buy a new one".

The way I interpreted the usage of のに is more like "Then we'll have to buy a new one." Is that correct or is there a more accurate translation?

Comment: I don't think かえましょう here means かう/買う to buy. I think this にかえましょう means to "to switch to..." -> "let's switch (the old one) to the new one (marked by に)". The の is there for a replacement for こと/もの, because it must be a noun.

Comment: @firuvi Good spot. I didn't read the question well enough. かえる certainly means 'change' and not 'buy'. Even if it was 'buy' it would have to be the potential form and the sentence would be weird in so many other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あたらしいをかえましょう is ungrammatical. あたらしい is an adjective, and the object of a sentence (thing marked by を) must be a noun or noun phrase.

あたらしい**の**をかえましょう would be grammatical but it would not have the correct meaning. The の here means 'one' and makes the adjective into a noun phrase. This sentence would mean "Let's change the new one". But, you want to change **to** the new one, hence に rather than を.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's crystal clear. What a mistake with かえる, I always believe it means buy instead of かう